# RuntimeException and GraphQLError in Kotlin and Java

Tags: java, kotlin, graphql

I try to develop a REST API with GraphQL and Kotlin and I'm facing the following problem: I try to create a custom Exception that extends RuntimeException and implements GraphQLError and in Kotlin I can not do this because I'm receiveing this: [Accidental override when using third party Java interface and extending RuntimeException in kotlin](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/accidental-override-when-using-third-party-java-interface-and-extending-runtimeexception-in-kotlin/7658).

I resolve this problem with an workaround by creating a Java class for my CustomException.

But I don't know why, when I create a kotlin class that extends `RuntimeException` and implements `GraphQLError`, I need to override the `getMessage()` method from GraphQLError, but when I create a java class that extends RuntimeException and implements GraphQLError I don't need to override the `getMessage()` method from GraphQLError.

Thank you!

Comment: I am not into Kotlin, but as I read it, this is a known problem in Kotlin that is not solved yet: [KT-24822](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24822) (and others)

Comment: Yeah, I understand that problem, but my question was about another fact: why I need to override the getMessage() method in Kotlin, but not in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Annotate message with @JvmField like:

```
class MyError(@JvmField override val message: String?, private val invalidField: String? = null) : RuntimeException(message), GraphQLError {

    override fun getMessage(): String = super.message ?: "no error message set"

    override fun getLocations(): List<SourceLocation> = emptyList()

    override fun getErrorType(): ErrorType = ErrorType.DataFetchingException

    override fun getExtensions(): Map<String, Any> = if(invalidField!=null)
        Collections.singletonMap<String, Any>("invalidField", invalidField)
    else
        Collections.emptyMap()
}
```

Comment: It is good practice to explain a bit about your answer for better understanding.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore, I get: `JvmField cannot be applied to a property that overrides some other property`

Answer (score 1):

It seems overriding a property accessor with a function is not yet seemlessly supported. It is currently a bug as per your link. This can be easily verified by a simple example like this one:

```
class Sample(val message : String) {
    fun getMessage() :String = "MyString"
}
```

This happens because the property `message` (in your case, the message from `Throwable`) and the `getMessage` function (in your case, the `getMessage` from GraphQL) converts to the same JVM signature. It seems to me that the current status quo is that property accessors are not treated as individual members so they cannot be overriden by member functions or even implement abstract functions. I am not sure why that is the case though.

Answer (score 0):

@Kisschr answer doesn't work anymore.
You have to add another annotation beside @JvmField so your code will look like this:

```
class MyError(
    @JvmField 
    @Suppress("INAPPLICABLE_JVM_FIELD")
    override val message: String?, 
    private val invalidField: String? = null
) : RuntimeException(message), GraphQLError {

    override fun getMessage(): String = super.message ?: "no error message set"

    override fun getLocations(): List<SourceLocation> = emptyList()

    override fun getErrorType(): ErrorType = ErrorType.DataFetchingException

    override fun getExtensions(): Map<String, Any> = if(invalidField!=null)
        Collections.singletonMap<String, Any>("invalidField", invalidField)
    else
        Collections.emptyMap()
}
```

This bug is caused by known Kotlin [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24822), kotlin property doesn't override RuntimeException getter for message. So you have to tell kotlin not to generate getter for this property.